# strftime: month short name isn't always the same

Tags: php, locale, strftime

I'm using strftime to get a shortened version of the month name. The wanted behaviour is to get 3 letters (in french locale in my case), Jan, Fev, Mar, etc.

It works fine on my Mac, but on the test server (a Linux box), i get other shortened version, like janv., sept. (with the dots) and so on.

How can it be changed in order to get 3 letters?

Here an example of a conversion:

```
$sDateFin = sprintf(" Fin %s", strftime("%d %b %Y", $tDateFin));
```

Comment: Have you tried `%h` instead of `%b`, to see if it produce the same?

Comment: The test server where it isn't working properly is owned by the customer, so it will be hard to experiment. I tried on my workstation, and it's still ok with %h. The PHP doc (http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strftime.php ) says %h is an alias of %b, so I don't think it will change anything...

Comment: Yes but I thought some different alias might be set in the server. Documentation says **base on locale** so did you set any locale before `setocale()`?

Comment: Documentation also says *Warning
The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS or Apache on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while a script is running, though the script itself never called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the process-wide locale using setlocale().*

Comment: So it's not really a reliable way to get a formatted string. Good to know.